# How do I encourage my Florence fennel to produce fat bulbs?

Tags: harvesting, bolting

I have some Florence fennel in my garden that tends to grow very fast in height and to make flowers, but the base stays relatively thin.

What should I do to encourage the growth of a "fat" bulb in order to have a better harvest? Does it help to cut it from time to time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Florence fennel is very fussy and prone to bolting when temperatures are variable, so it could be bolting if you're sowing/planting it new each year. In this case, I suggest trying to protect it from temperature extremes. If you've been growing fennel in the same position year upon year, it could be that the soil needs enriching. Also, it's a biennial, so it's unlikely to produce sufficiently inflated stems after its first year.